# How can I transform a value from a dictionary to a key and build a nested dictionary with the subsequent values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm new to dict structures and I have the following:

```
d = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'x':111, 'y': 222, 'z':333}
```

And I want to change to the following structure:

```
d2 = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'cc':{ 'x':111, 'y': 222, 'z':333}}
```

Basically, the `value` of a given `key` will become the `key` itself and subsequent `values` will go into this new key as a nested dict.The values of `x`, `y` and `z` are demonstrative only, they can be floats or integers. Always after the `c` key, will come the values that need to be placed inside `c`. Thank you

Comment: why it applies only to  `c` key?

Comment: Are you assuming that keys are ordered in a dict? I'm guessing what you want to do is (assuming dict keys are ordered) to merge items into the previous item (converting the previous item to a dict) whenever the value is an integer.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The keys `a`, `b` and `c` are keys that represent the dict. `x`, `y` and `z` are the values I need to put inside `c`. Always after the `c` will have the values

Comment: @Fractalism Keys and values are for demonstration purposes only and from `c` onwards they can be either floats or intergers. But always after `c`, the elements that need to be placed inside `c` start, that's for sure

Comment: @Syner, your `d2` shows `cc` and not `c`, can you _double-check_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little longer solution fitted for more general cases:

```
d = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'x':111, 'y': 222, 'z':333}

slicing_key = 'c'
svalue = d[slicing_key]

d2 = {}
d2[svalue] = {}

# List of all keys
all_keys = list(d.keys())
# Index of the key where you slice
slice_ind = all_keys.index(slicing_key)
# Unchanged entries
orig_keys = all_keys[:slice_ind]
# Keys for entries in the inner dict
new_keys = all_keys[slice_ind+1:]

# Assemble the new dictionary
for key in orig_keys:
    d2[key] = d[key]

for key in new_keys:
    d2[svalue][key] = d[key]
```

First you pre-define your output dictionary, then you split up the list of all keys based on your slicing key criterion, and finally you assemble the new dictionary.

Note that this relies on the fact that the list returned by `keys()` is ordered. It should be this way now but you can also sort it to be on the safe side, `all_keys = list(sorted(d.keys()))`.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky solution would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) *constructor* from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
import pandas as pd

def nest_dict(d, val):
    v = next((k for k, v in d.items() if v == val), None)
    df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
    idx = df.columns.get_loc(v)
    out = df.iloc[:, :idx].to_dict("records")[0]
    out[val] = df.iloc[:, idx+1:].to_dict("records")[0]
    return out

d2 = nest_dict(d1, "cc")
```

Output :

```
print(d2)
#{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'cc': {'x': 111, 'y': 222, 'z': 333}}
```

Comment: `pandas` seems a bit heavy for a simple problem like this...

Comment: That's why I said _tricky_. And feel free to post your approach if you assume it's lighter/faster ;).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a vague question and more details regarding the constraints/rules should be provided. However, with the given details, here is a piece of code that should help you out.

```
import itertools
def slice_dic(dic, k):
    keys = list(dic)
    lts = keys.index(k)
    d = dict(itertools.islice(dic.items(), lts))
    d2 = dict(itertools.islice(dic.items(), lts+1,len(keys)))
    d[list(dic.values())[lts]] = d2
    return d

input_dict = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'x':111, 'y': 222, 'z':333}
slice_dic(input_dict, "c") #slices the dictionary at c 
                  #and keeps all subsequent key:value pairs as a dictinoary
```

The above snippet gives the following output:

```
{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'cc': {'x': 111, 'y': 222, 'z': 333}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With limited information present and without using any libraries

```
def spl_dict(d, pos):
    d2 = dict(list(d.items())[:pos-1])
    d2[list(d.values())[pos-1]]= dict(list(d.items())[pos:])
    return d2
print(spl_dict(d,3))
```

Output :

```
{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'cc': {'x': 111, 'y': 222, 'z': 333}}
```

Comment: @Syner please check if you want a function that has a parameter position or a dictionary key?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you hold an insertion order of your input dict, the solution with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) util to get sequential groups counting on `c` key:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'x':111, 'y': 222, 'z':333}
head, c, tail = [list(gr) for _, gr in groupby(d.items(), lambda t: t[0] == 'c')]
c_k, c_v = c[0]  # for c key
res = {**dict(head), **{c_v: dict(tail)}}
```

---

```
{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'cc': {'x': 111, 'y': 222, 'z': 333}}
```